# How call reference (TextView)findViewById from another class

Tags: android, view

I have created a function that updates some values from a database that I need to use on multiple views.  Right now each class has its own copy of the code.  Basically I read the values and then want to update the text views.

I made a class for the DisplayTop which does the work, and locally its great.  But somehow I need to get the (TextView)findViewById sent over the the function I think.  I hope I am saying this right.  So what is the call to this and how to I resolved the (TextView)findViewById.  thanks for any help!

```
 public void DisplayTop2()
 {


  int UserID = 1;
  String D=Fun.getCurrentDateString();
  String Sql;

  Double a = 0.0;
  Double b = 0.0;

  SQLiteDatabase Db;

  String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
  Db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);



  Sql =" SELECT a,b " +
  " FROM test " +
  " where Dte = '" + D + "' and UserID = " + UserID;

  try {
   Cursor c = Db.rawQuery(Sql, null);

   if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
     do {


      a +=  (c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("a")));

      b +=  (c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("b")));

     }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
   }

   c.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
  Db.close();

  // Here is where the problem is.  The real app has 5 fields.
  // I can pass the R.id.a
  // But how do I pass the reference to findViewById to the activity that called this

  TextView tvt4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.a);
  D = Fun.round( a,1,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  tvt4.setText( D )  ;

   tvt4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.b);
  D = Fun.round( b,1,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  tvt4.setText( D )  ;



 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would try and keep all the UI updates within my `Activity`, rather than passing around `TextView` objects.  Why not create a `Bean` to populate and return to the calling activity?  Something like:

```
public class Mybean {
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    // create constructor and getters and setters here
}
```

Then populate and return the bean in your database code.

```
public MyBean DisplayTop2() {
    ...
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.setFieldA(Fun.round( a,1,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    bean.setFieldB(Fun.round( b,1,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    return bean;
}
```

Then populate the UI in your `Activity`:

```
...
MyBean bean = MyDBClass.DisplayTop2();
TextView txtA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextviewA);
TextView txtB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextviewB);
txtA.setText(bean.getFieldA());
txtB.setText(bean.getFieldB());
```

This keeps all your UI code separate from your DB code.

Comment: Another cheater way to do it would be to pass the Context from the Activity, but your solution is much cleaner.

Comment: or even passing the Activity itself, this could be useful sometimes, but I agree, @dave.c's solution is the most elegant.

Comment: So the code I added here was short.  there are 5 fields that all need color changes etc and it winds up to be about 30 lines of code in each of the activities.  So its ok to just have that code duplicated basically in each activity?  I was trying to make a function that did it all in one place.  but lots easier to leave it as it is :)

Comment: Well your UI parts are each specific to the `Activity` they are within.  However your database access class containing your `DisplayTop2()` method can be in one central place that each activity can call.  There is no duplication of code as each UI update will be slightly different as you are updating a different set of `TextView`. You also only need write your database code once.